# Objects not appearing in array in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I thought this count would return 26, but it returns zero.  a-z are uninitialized UIImageViews.  Do you now what  the problem could be?

```
 NSMutableArray *letters = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects: a,b,c,d,e,f,g,self.h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z, nil];


 NSLog(@"%d",(int)[letters count]);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`initWithObjects:` will add any object till it finds the first `nil`. As you said, your image vies aren't initialized, they all are nil. Hence the first is nil. Hence no object is added. Therefore 0 is the correct count.

You just can add instantiated objects to an array.

Comment: To summarize: his initialization of letters equals to  `NSMutableArray *letters = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects: nil]`

Answer (score 1):

Question: How initWithObjects work?
Answer: it insert all objects until it reach nil.
What you really did is the following:

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects: nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil];
```

You got your answer.

anyway. even if that worked. there is no benefit at all. even if images got initialised it have nothing to do with array. because you simply inserted nils on it and not a reference to anything, it's a nil.

you must initialise those first.

Comment: now it is 80% copy of my answer and 20% wrong. calling `addObject:` 26 times will nil won't work. so there will be no count of 26. `addObject:` crashes with nil.